# Need help using .join() to turn an array into a list of strings

Tags: arrays, string

**Everything works but I can't for the life of me remove the brackets.**

```
console.log(overusedWordArray)

//[ 'really',
  'basically',
  'really',
  'very',
  'very',
  'very',
  'very',
  'very' ]


const getFrequency = (array) => {
  let overusedWordCount= [];
   array.forEach(word => {
      if(overusedWordCount[word]){
         overusedWordCount[word]++;
      }else{
         overusedWordCount[word] = 1;
      }
   });
   return overusedWordCount;
};
console.log(getFrequency(overusedWordArray));

//[ really: 2, basically: 1, very: 5 ]
```

**I have tried:**

```
overusedWordCount=overusedWordCount.join('');
return overusedWordCount;
    };
    console.log(getFrequency(overusedWordArray));
```

**and it showed nothing.
I have also tried:**

```
newOverusedWordCount=overusedWordCount.join('');
return newOverusedWordCount;
    };
    console.log(getFrequency(overusedWordArray));
```

**and it showed nothing.
And I also tried:**

```
return overusedWordCount.join('');
    };
    console.log(getFrequency(overusedWordArray));
```

**HELP**

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why all of these are failing are because they are key val arrays, which aren't supported by the majority of either array, nor object values. The reason is because the iterator (which loops over arrays whenever an array function is called) does not have the index of the elements which you've added.

A workaround is:

```
console.log(Object(getFrequency(overusedWordArray)).values().join(' '));
```

Luckily, Object.values() works on both, arrays and objects.

Comment: Hi! So I replaced my console log with yours and I got: TypeError: Object(...).values is not a function, is there something I need to change within my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a String with all the words? Or you need to know how many words are repetead in the array? Because are 2 different things. And your const is `getFrequency` that's why I'm asking you.

If you need to return a unique String I suggest to do this:

```
function getFrequency(array) {
  return array.join(' ');
}
```

This function will concat every element in the array with a space between.

Comment: Hi! I want it to return exactly like //[ really: 2, basically: 1, very: 5 ] but without the brackets.

Comment: I understand. I'm not sure how to do it. I have poor experience with JS. I think you must try to convert it to String, with another for loop where you concant each word with its corresponding counting and without repeating them. I don't know another way. I'm a new Java Dev, so I think in "Java's ways"..